# Can't start MySql from powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I've installed MySQL 5.7 on windows 10 and can get it to work from the workbench but every time I try to launch it from the powershell it gives me this error.

[image]

Help anyone?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$env:PATH`? Does it contain the folder that contains the `mysql` command?

Comment: Ensure mysql executeable path is within your path using `$env:Path -split ';'`

Comment: As instructed in the error message, have you tried to run `.\mysql` ? You can also add the location to `PATH` in `$env`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because. The mysql is not added in the path of the windows. Thats why this happens. Initially grab the location of mysql.exe. 
find it from the installation directory.

In my case mysql.exe is in the folder `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` yours may vary depending upon your installation.

Then right click on This Pc->Properties-> Advanced System Settings(on the left side).

you will get a dialouge box. Click on environment variables
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNCEV.jpg)

Find Path under system variables(Bottom side of the popup window). Click Edit[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vedvx.jpg)

Click New on the right side. Paste the path of mysql there. Click OK. Then Restart power shell

Now Mysql command should be working.

Comment: Hi I've tried to add this to the path but it still doesn't work in powershell.

Weirdly enough when use the command prompt, mysql starts up?

I'm a real newbie trying to teach myself, so sorry if I'm missing something basic here. 

Is there a reason it works on command prompt but not powershell?

Thanks

Comment: Hi I've found out if I follow what it says and use ./mysql -u root -p, it works

Just curious, how come I have to do this and not just start it up without the ./ in command prompt.

(side note: coding is really difficult with all this little diferences lol)

Comment: @Ystan the answer is found by listing your PATH.  Use `$ENV:PATH` and look for `c:\program files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin`  if it's not listed, add it using the steps given by @Shobi P P